# dotenv | process.env.NAME Not Working When Being Called in Config File

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

I am trying to wrap up `.env` values inside config file. It is working when being called on another file (ie: server.js). But returning `undefined` when called inside `config.js` file.

**Folder Structure**

```
root
-- server
---- server.js
-- .env
-- config.js
```

---

**.env**

```
MAIL_USER = email@gmail.com
PORT = 8000
```

---

**config.js**

```
const mailUser = process.env.MAIL_USER;
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

module.exports = {
mailUser,
PORT
}
```

---

**server.js**

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import app from "./express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import config from "../config";

... // some other settings are defined here // ...

app.listen(3000, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }  
  console.log(`Server running on port ${config.PORT}`);
  console.log(process.env.MAIL_USER);
  console.log(mailUser);
});
```

---

**OUTPUT ON THE CONSOLE**

```
email@gmail.com
undefined
```

What will be the problem so that the `process.env.MAIL_USER` is `undefined` when being called inside `config.js` file and how to solve it?

Comment: Try renaming to APP_NAME_PORT instead. I've run into this before, I don't have an explanation for it though

Answer (score 2):

You are loading `dotenv` extension in your `server.js` file, that's why your ENV variables are not visible in `config.js`, try loading them at your `config.js` like you did:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
```

As was suggested before, you can run your script without importing `dotenv` lib in your code:

```
node -r dotenv/config server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try import dotenv from 'dotenv' and then try using dotenv.config()
It is mentioned in How do I use dotenv with import?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to keep your config.js just to export those properties, you'd have to add the import for *dotenv* as well as `dotenv.config()`. Then you can call the exported values directly from that file, without re-importing dotenv in your server.js file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, restarting the server solved the problem.

Also, keep in mind that you're exporting both variables in the `config.js` file but only consuming `PORT` variable from this file.

Answer (score 0):

`import dotenv/config;` instead of `dotenv`

Note: you do not need to call dotenv.config() and must pass options via the command line or environment variables with this approach

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import-